# How to increase the performance of inserting data into the database?

Tags: performance, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I use PostgreSQL 9.5 (and a newest JDBC driver - 9.4.1209), JPA 2.1 (Hibernate), EJB 3.2, CDI, JSF 2.2 and Wildfly 10. I've to insert a lot of data into the database (about 1 mln - 170 mln entities). The number of entities depends on a file which user will add to the form on the page.

## What is the problem?

The problem is the execution time of inserting data into the database which is very slow. The execution time is growing every calling of the `flush()` method. I've put the `println(...)` method to know how fast the execution of the `flush` method is. For the first ~4 times (400000 entities), I receive result of the `println(...)` method every ~20s. Later, the execution time of the `flush` method is incredibly slow and it's still growing.

Of course, if I delete the `flush()` and `clear()` methods, I receive result of the `println(...)` method every 1s BUT when I approach to the 3 mln entities, I also receive the exception:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

## What have I done so far?

- I've tried with the Container-Managed Transactions and the Bean-Managed Transactions as well (look at the code below).
- I don't use the `auto_increment` feature for the PK ID. I add the IDs manually in the bean code.
- I've also tried to change the number of the entities to flush (at the moment 100000).
- I've tried to set the same number of the entities like in the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property. It didn't help, the execution time was much slower.
- I've tried to experiment with the properties in the `persistence.xml` file. For example, I added the `reWriteBatchedInserts` property but indeed I don't know if it could help.
- The PostgreSQL is running on the SSD but the data are stored on the HDD because the data could be to big in the future. But I've tried to move my PostgreSQL data to the SSD and the result is the same, nothing has changed.

The question is: **How can I increase the performance of inserting data into database?**

Here's the structure of my table:

```
  column_name  |   udt_name  | length | is_nullable |  key
---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+--------
id             |    int8     |        |     NO      |   PK
id_user_table  |    int4     |        |     NO      |   FK
starttime      | timestamptz |        |     NO      |
time           |   float8    |        |     NO      |
sip            |   varchar   |  100   |     NO      |
dip            |   varchar   |  100   |     NO      |
sport          |    int4     |        |     YES     |
dport          |    int4     |        |     YES     |
proto          |   varchar   |   50   |     NO      |
totbytes       |    int8     |        |     YES     |
info           |    text     |        |     YES     |
label          |   varchar   |   10   |     NO      |
```

Here's part of the EJB bean (**first version**) where I insert the data into the database:

```
@Stateless
public class DataDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Data> implements DataDao {

    /**
     * This's the first method which is executed. 
     * The CDI bean (controller) calls this method.
     * @param list - data from the file.
     * @param idFK - foreign key.
     */
    public void send(List<String> list, int idFK) {

        if(handleCSV(list,idFK)){
            //...
        }
        else{
            //...
        }
    }

    /**
     * The method inserts data into the database.
     */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private boolean handleCSV(List<String> list, int idFK){

        try{

            long start=0;
            Pattern patternRow=Pattern.compile(",");

            for (String s : list) {

                if(start!=0){

                    String[] data=patternRow.split(s);                  

                    //Preparing data...

                    DataStoreAll dataStore=new DataStoreAll();
                    DataStoreAllId dataId=new DataStoreAllId(start++, idFK);                    
                    dataStore.setId(dataId);

                    //Setting the other object fields...                                                    

                    entityManager.persist(dataStore);               

                    if(start%100000==0){
                        System.out.println("Number of entities: "+start);
                        entityManager.flush();
                        entityManager.clear();                      
                    }
                }
                else start++;
            }                       

        } catch(Throwable t){

            CustomExceptionHandler exception=new CustomExceptionHandler(t);
            return exception.persist("DDI", "handleCSV");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Instead of using the Container-Managed Transactions, I've tried to use Bean-Managed Transactions either (**second version**):

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class DataDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Data> {
    /**
     * This's the first method which is executed. 
     * The CDI bean (controller) calls this method.
     * @param list - data from the file.
     * @param idFK - foreign key.
     */
    public void send(List<String> list, int idFK) {

        if(handleCSV(list,idFK)){
            //...
        }
        else{
            //...
        }
    }

    /**
     * The method inserts data into the linkedList collection.
     */
    private boolean handleCSV(List<String> list, int idFK){

        try{

            long start=0;
            Pattern patternRow=Pattern.compile(",");
            List<DataStoreAll> entitiesAll=new LinkedList<>();

            for (String s : list) {

                if(start!=0){

                    String[] data=patternRow.split(s);                  

                    //Preparing data...

                    DataStoreAll dataStore=new DataStoreAll();
                    DataStoreAllId dataId=new DataStoreAllId(start++, idFK);                    
                    dataStore.setId(dataId);

                    //Setting the other object fields...                                                    

                    entitiesAll.add(dataStore);

                    if(start%100000==0){

                        System.out.println("Number of entities: "+start);
                        saveDataStoreAll(entitiesAll);                      
                    }
                }
                else start++;
            }

        } catch(Throwable t){

            CustomExceptionHandler exception=new CustomExceptionHandler(t);
            return exception.persist("DDI", "handleCSV");
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * The method commits the transaction.
     */
    private void saveDataStoreAll(List<DataStoreAll> entities) throws EntityExistsException,IllegalArgumentException,TransactionRequiredException,PersistenceException,Throwable {

        Iterator<DataStoreAll> iter=entities.iterator();

        ut.begin();     

        while(iter.hasNext()){

            entityManager.persist(iter.next());
            iter.remove();
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }

        ut.commit();
    }

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction ut;
}
```

Here's my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />         
         <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
         <property name="reWriteBatchedInserts" value="true"/>         
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If I forgot to add something, tell me about it and I'll update my post.

## Update

Here's the controller which calls `DataDaoImpl#send(...)`:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DataController implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){

        //...
    }

    /**
     * Handle of the uploaded file.
     */
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){

        uploadFile=event.getFile();

        try(InputStream input = uploadFile.getInputstream()){

            Path folder=Paths.get(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"),"upload");

            if(!folder.toFile().exists()){
                if(!folder.toFile().mkdirs()){
                    folder=Paths.get(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"));
                }
            }

            String filename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(uploadFile.getFileName()); 
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadFile.getFileName());
            filePath = Files.createTempFile(folder, filename + "-", "." + extension);

            //Save the file on the server.
            Files.copy(input, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            //Add reference to the unconfirmed uploaded files list.
            userFileManager.addUnconfirmedUploadedFile(filePath.toFile());

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", uploadFile.getFileName() + " was uploaded."));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            //...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sending data from file to the database.
     */
    public void send(){

        //int idFK=...

        //The model includes the data from the file and other things which I transfer to the EJB bean.
        AddDataModel addDataModel=new AddDataModel();       
        //Setting the addDataModel fields...        

        try{

            if(uploadFile!=null){

                //Each row of the file == 1 entity.
                List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

                Stream<String> stream=Files.lines(filePath);
                list=stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

                addDataModel.setList(list);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            //...
        }   

        //Sending data to the DataDaoImpl EJB bean.
        if(dataDao.send(addDataModel,idFK)){

            userFileManager.confirmUploadedFile(filePath.toFile());

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "The data was saved in the database.", ""));
        }       
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7202741739427929050L;

    @Inject
    private DataDao dataDao;

    private UserFileManager userFileManager;
    private UploadedFile uploadFile;
    private Path filePath;
}
```

## Update 2

Here's the updated EJB bean where I insert the data into the database:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class DataDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Data> {

    /**
     * This's the first method which is executed. 
     * The CDI bean (controller) calls this method.
     * @param addDataModel - object which includes path to the uploaded file and other things which are needed.
     */ 
    public void send(AddDataModel addDataModel){

        if(handleCSV(addDataModel)){
            //...
        }
        else{
            //...
        }
    }

    /**
     * The method inserts data into the database.
     */
    private boolean handleCSV(AddDataModel addDataModel){

        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        Connection con=null;

        FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
        Scanner scanner=null;       

        try{

            con=ds.getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into data_store_all "
                    + "(id,id_user_table,startTime,time,sIP,dIP,sPort,dPort,proto,totBytes,info) "
                    + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            long start=0;       

            fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(addDataModel.getPath().toFile());
            scanner=new Scanner(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");

            Pattern patternRow=Pattern.compile(",");            
            Pattern patternPort=Pattern.compile("\\d+");

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                if(start!=0){

                    //Loading a row from the file into table.

                    String[] data=patternRow.split(scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("[\"]",""));

                    //Preparing datetime.

                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");                                                          
                    GregorianCalendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar();
                    calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(data[1]));
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Integer.parseInt(Pattern.compile("\\.").split(data[1])[1])/1000);

                    //Preparing an entity

                    ps.setLong(1, start++); //id PK
                    ps.setInt(2, addDataModel.getIdFk()); //id FK
                    ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime())); //datetime
                    ps.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(data[2])); //time
                    ps.setString(5, data[3]); //sip
                    ps.setString(6, data[4]); //dip

                    if(!data[5].equals("") && patternPort.matcher(data[5]).matches()) ps.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(data[5])); //sport
                    else ps.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

                    if(!data[6].equals("") && patternPort.matcher(data[6]).matches()) ps.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(data[6])); //dport
                    else ps.setNull(8, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

                    ps.setString(9, data[7]); //proto

                    if(!data[8].trim().equals("")) ps.setLong(10, Long.parseLong(data[8])); //len
                    else ps.setObject(10, null);

                    if(data.length==10 && !data[9].trim().equals("")) ps.setString(11, data[9]); //info
                    else ps.setString(11, null);

                    ps.addBatch();

                    if(start%100000==0){
                        System.out.println("Number of entity: "+start);

                        ps.executeBatch();
                        ps.clearParameters();
                        ps.clearBatch();
                        con.commit();                       
                    }
                }
                else{
                    start++;
                    scanner.nextLine();
                }
            }

            if (scanner.ioException() != null) throw scanner.ioException();

        } catch(Throwable t){

            CustomExceptionHandler exception=new CustomExceptionHandler(t);
            return exception.persist("DDI", "handleCSV");
        } finally{

            if (fileInputStream!=null)
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (Throwable t2) {
                    CustomExceptionHandler exception=new CustomExceptionHandler(t2);
                    return exception.persist("DDI", "handleCSV.Finally");
                }
            if (scanner != null) scanner.close();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource(mappedName="java:/PostgresDS") 
    private DataSource ds;
}
```

Comment: Hibernate is not the best tool for this job. I would just use a JDBC batch statement, and I would commit (not just flush) every N rows.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll try that.

Comment: IMHO it is not just Hibernate, but *any* ORM will suffer from database <--> app *impedance mismatch* eventually. And: loading stuff into core before pushing it into a stream will always be expensive. [an "objective" measure for this is the ratio DBMS/app for {CPU,IO} ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not necessarily the database or even hibernate, but that you are loading way too much data into memory at once.  That's why you get the out of memory message and why you see the jvm struggling on the way there.

You read the file from a stream, but then push it all into memory when you create the the list of strings. Then you map that list of strings into a linked list of some sort of entity!

Instead, use the the stream to process your files in small chunks and insert the chunks into your database.  A scanner based approach would look something like this:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // Talk to your database here!
    }
    // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

You'll probably find the hibernate/ejb stuff works well enough after you make this change.  But I think you'll find plain jdbc to be significantly faster. They say you can expect a 3x to 4x speed bump, depending. That would to make a big difference with a lot of data.

If you are talking about truly huge amounts of data then you should look into the [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html), that lets you load streams directly into the database.  You can use the streaming apis to transform the data as it goes by.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I use the streams (like in the updated post) but at the end I load a lot of data into memory (the `list` variable in the `DataDaoImpl#handleCSV()` stores each row of the file) as you wrote. Based on your solution I'll try to change my code and I'll give you feedback soon how it works.

Comment: You were right. I've change my code and I've used the JDBC batch statement. I had to mix JPA and JDBC to work together in my system (I assume that I've done it correctly). At the moment, each 100000 entities are commited every 10-20 sec (not only first four times). Unfortunately it's still to long. Imagine 170 mln entities... Look at the updated post. Is it correct? Can I do anything else?

Comment: You've done all you can to improve your code.  If the inserts are too slow, try the CopyManager. I have ammended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using WildFly 10, you are in a Java EE 7 environment.

Therefore you should consider using JSR-352 Batch Processing for performing your file import.

Have a look at [An Overview of Batch Processing in Java EE 7.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html).

This should resolve all your memory consumption and transaction issues.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try that later as well.

Comment: That looks promising.

Comment: @SteveC, how should it look like in my case? Could you give me some example of the implementation of the `Batch Processing` in my case?

Comment: Did you read the link that I provided? It has plenty of sample code in it